# django cannot get static css to work in template base.html

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I am trying to setup a site wide css file.

My css will render if I place it directly in my block content

```
cat register/templates/register/register.html        
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Create an Account{% endblock %}


{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<style>
.registration_base {
        padding-top: 50px;
        margin: auto;
        width: 30%;
}
</style>

<div class="registration_base">

        <form method="POST" class="form-group">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
        </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

and it will function fine but I would like the code called from a style.css file site wide, in my base.html file.

I cannot get the css file to actually render.

In my

```
templates/base.html
```

I have 
UPDATED:

```
$ cat templates/base.html        
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Universal Trader</title>
        {% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare
.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "/static/style.css" %}>


</head>
<body>

        {% include 'navbar.html' %}
        {% block content %}
                replace me
        {% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

in my

```
register/static/style.css
```

I have the same css code:

```
.registration_base {
        padding-top: 50px;
        margin: auto;
        width: 30%;
}
```

I can run

```
#python3 manage.py findstatic style.css
Found 'style.css' here:
  /home/user/www/src/register/static/style.css
```

and it finds it, but my css formatting never changes.

I have the app installed in

```
site/settings.py


INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'pages',
        'register.apps.RegisterConfig',
        'crispy_forms',
]
```

updated settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

updated nginx/sites-enabled/site static info.

```
server{
        location /static {
                alias /home/user/www/src/exchange/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
        }
    }
```

How do I get a site wide css file properly included?

Updated:

```
#cat register/forms.py

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User    

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
        email = forms.EmailField()

        class Meta:
                model = User
                fields = ["username", "password1", "password2", "email"]
```

and

```
#cat register/views.py        
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import RegisterForm

# Create your views here.
def register(response):
        if response.method == "POST":
                form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()

                return redirect("/")
        else:
                form = RegisterForm()

        form = RegisterForm()
        return render(response, "register/register.html",{"form":form})
```

UPDATED:

I can browse the url

```
http://192.168.42.13:8080/static/style.css
```

just fine, but my base.html cannot, appearantly

I rebooted the server. Same issue.

UPDATED again:

even

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "http://192.168.42.13/static/style.css" %}>
```

fails in base.html

Comment: So does Nginx find this file? Which response status do you get on this CSS URL request?

Comment: @IvanStarostin I cannot reach/find the style.css file from any url. It's as though it is refusing to be made public.

Comment: So which HTTP status do you get in response? 404? 403? 500?

Comment: @IvanStarostin I just updated. Wow, I can surf to http://192.168.42.13:8080/static/style.css just find but my base.html cannot read the same public file. I'm must be screwing up bad some where.

Comment: So the style.css is accessible, URL is fine, but it does not apply to your page, right? 1) Fix your stylesheets definition - move them all to `head` 2) put your own css the very last in this list.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I fixed the </head> issues and put the css last. same issue. Updated the post also.

Comment: This means this issue has no connection to Django - it's just about styles themselves. _Inspect_ elements and check which classes and styles are applied to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the use of the 'static' tag, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#static. The link in your base.html would then be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
```

Don't forget to load the tag at the top of your template:

```
{% load static %}
```

You can specify where Django is looking for static files in the STATICFILES_DIRS parameter in your settings file, like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs for more information how to set this.

Comment: These changes to not have any effect.  :(

Comment: It looks like your style.css is in the BASE_DIR, judging from your findstatic outcome /register/static/style.css (I missed that). In that case try os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') in STATICFILES_DIRS, instead of what I suggested above.

Comment: I tried STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/'),
], then  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static'), then  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'). Same issue.

Comment: I see you have updated your href to {% static "/static/style.css" %}. The way I understand this works is that Django looks for the paths in STATICFILES_DIRS, appends the described subdirectory 'static' to the BASE_DIR, and then looks for the filename. So when the file is /home/user/www/src/register/static/style.css, then your BASE_DIR is /home/user/www/src/register/, the setting should be STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/') (not sure whether / is necessary, and the html code should be "{% static 'style.css' %}". Don't forget double quotes outside and single quotes inside.

Comment: Thank you sincerely!